Consulta Entity Framework multitablas
Estoy aprendiendo con entity framework en c# y quiero hacer un login con credenciales que retorne si el usuario se logueó correctamente, los códigos de credencial que le corresponden, los cuales pondré de condición en cada uno de los métodos así se si puede o no acceder al mismo. Primero explico: la solución tiene 5 proyectos (Entidades, Datos, Negocio, Front y Entity Framework). A continuación muestro cada una de las partes

Tablas Creadas:

CREATE TABLE Usuarios (
    IdUsuario           INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
    IdPersona           INT                             NOT NULL,
    NombreUsuario       VARCHAR(100)                    NOT NULL,
    ClaveUsuario        VARCHAR(100)                    NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (IdPersona) REFERENCES Personas(IdPersona)
);
CREATE TABLE Credenciales (
    IdCredencial        INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
    TipoCredencial      VARCHAR(100)                    NOT NULL,
    CodigoCredencial    VARCHAR(20)                     NOT NULL,
    PermisosOtorgados   VARCHAR(150)                    NULL
);
CREATE TABLE UsuariosCredenciales (
    IdUsuarioCredencial     INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
    IdUsuario               INT                             NOT NULL,
    IdCredencial            INT                             NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (IdUsuario) REFERENCES Usuarios(IdUsuario)          ,
    FOREIGN KEY (IdCredencial) REFERENCES Credenciales(IdCredencial)
);


Entidades Creadas


    public class Credenciales
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdCredencial { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string? TipoCredencial { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string? CodigoCredencial { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string? PermisosOtorgados { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Usuarios
    
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdUsuario {  get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string? NombreUsuario { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string? ClaveUsuario { get; set; }
    } 
    
    public class UsuariosCredenciales
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdUsuarioCredencial { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Usuario")]
        public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Credenciales")]
        public int IdCredencial { get; set; }
        public Usuarios? Usuario { get; set; }
        public Credenciales? Credenciales { get; set; }
        [NotMapped] //Para que busque el codigo que me interesa
        public string? CodigoCredencial
        {
            get
            {
                if (Credenciales != null)
                    return Credenciales.CodigoCredencial;
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }


Métodos creados:

DATOS
    public static List<string?> Accesos(Usuarios e)
    {
        ringoContext = new RingoDbContext();
        List<string?> accesos = new();
        accesos = ringoContext.UsuariosCredenciales
        .Where(uc => uc.IdUsuario == e.IdUsuario)
        .Select(uc => uc.CodigoCredencial)
        .ToList();
        return accesos;
    }


Negocio
    public static List<string?> Permisos(Usuarios u)
    {
    
        List<string?> credenciales = new();
        try
        {
            credenciales = RingoDatosEF.Accesos(u);
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string nula = ex.Message;
            credenciales.Add(nula);
        }
    
        return credenciales;
    } 

Front
    List<string?> acceso = new();
    acceso = LoginUsuario.Permisos(parametro);
    string mensaje = "Codigos de acceso: \n";
    if ( acceso != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < acceso.Count(); i++)
        {
            mensaje += acceso.ElementAt(i);
            if (i == acceso.Count() - 1)
                mensaje += "!";
            else
                mensaje += "\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mensaje = "\n No tiene codigos de acceso";
    }

Las otras consultas simples me funcionan correctamente y el usuario que ingreso tiene 2 credenciales a su nombre. Pero cuando logueo el mensaje vuelve vacío. Quiero aprender así porque quería evolucionar de ADO.
La consulta en sql server que me devuelve los datos que necesito es:
    select NombreUsuario, CodigoCredencial
    from Usuarios as U, UsuariosCredenciales as UC, Credenciales as C
    where U.IdUsuario = UC.IdUsuario and UC.IdCredencial = C.IdCredencial and U.IdUsuario = 1

En este ejemplo el 1 es porque es el usuario que cargué para ejemplo con 2 credenciales.
Ahora quisiera saber en que le estoy errando para que me retorne vacía la lista.

No le coloques la ForeignKey a los Id's en la clase UsuariosCredenciales, colócalos en los métodos así:
public class UsuariosCredenciales
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdUsuarioCredencial { get; set; }
        public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
        public int IdCredencial { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("IdUsuario")]
        public Usuarios? Usuario { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("IdCredencial")]
        public Credenciales? Credenciales { get; set; }
        [NotMapped] //Para que busque el codigo que me interesa
        public string? CodigoCredencial
        {
            get
            {
                if (Credenciales != null)
                    return Credenciales.CodigoCredencial;
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }

Espero te sirva.

Probé hacerlo pero sigue igual, creo que el problema está en la capa datos pero no logro descifrar como hacer la consulta

Solucionado era que estaba enviando un usuario con Id nulo y por defecto el int viaja como cero asi que no traia nulo sino cero por eso no me daba error, ya corregí y funciona perfecto.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
